# Error creating table in MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql, sql, ddl, create-table

Can some one help me in correcting the syntax according to MySQL 5.7?

Table :

```
CREATE TABLE Employee(  
EMPID   INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
    EMPNAME VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,  
    EMPAGE  INT NOT NULL,  
    SALARY BIGINT NOT NULL,  
    ADDRESS VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL  
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)  
 );
```

**Error :**

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(ID)

Comment: Salary BIGINT? I'm in the wrong job :-(

Answer (score 3):

You forgot comma at the end of this line:

```
ADDRESS VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
```

You dont have a column named `ID`, you may want `EMPID`?

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems here:

1. A `primary key` clause is it's own clause, and needs to be separated from the previous column definition by a comma.
2. You don't have an `id` column - your primary key should (probably) be `empid`:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee(
    EMPID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    EMPNAME VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    EMPAGE INT NOT NULL,
    SALARY BIGINT NOT NULL,
    ADDRESS VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (EMPID)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace

`ADDRESS VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL`

By

`ADDRESS VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,`

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you are looking for:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee(
EMPID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
EMPNAME VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
EMPAGE INT NOT NULL,
SALARY BIGINT NOT NULL,
ADDRESS VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);
```